# How to create a schedulable function in Kotlin, that can be scheduled many times within delay interval, but run once at the end of the interval?

Tags: javascript, kotlin, asynchronous, kotlin-coroutines

How to create a function, that can be invoked many times **from non suspending context** and after the specific delay since the first invokation, the suspendable function runs?

Javascript code i'm trying to recreate in Kotlin:

```js
const DELAY_MS = 500

const sleep = (ms) => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms))
const schedulable = () => console.log('schedulable function is running')
let timeout = null

const schedule = () => {
  if (!timeout) {
    timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      timeout = null
      schedulable()
    }, DELAY_MS)
  }
}

;(async () => {
  schedule()
  await sleep(100)
  schedule()
  schedule()
  await sleep(200)
  schedule()
})()

// result: 'schedulable function is running' is printed once
```

Kotlin attempt (seems to work, but uses GlobalScope):

```kotlin
object SchedulableAttempt {
  private fun schedulable() {
    println("schedulable function is running")
  }

  private const val DELAY_MS = 500L
  private var deferred: Deferred<Unit>? = null

  fun schedule() {
    synchronized(this){
      if(deferred === null){
        deferred = GlobalScope.async {
          delay(DELAY_MS)
          deferred = null
          schedulable()
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

fun main() {
  thread {
    SchedulableAttempt.schedule()
    Thread.sleep(100)
    SchedulableAttempt.schedule()
    SchedulableAttempt.schedule()
    Thread.sleep(200)
    SchedulableAttempt.schedule()
  }

  runBlocking { // just to keep the app running
    delay(1000)
  }
}
```

How to do this in Kotlin properly? Does such solution have any pitfalls? **Kotlin documentation explicitly says to avoid using GlobalScope in cases, that are not top-level coroutines**, since it can create memory leaks

Comment: You will need to create a `CoroutineScope` that is not `GlobalScope` and pass it into `schedule`.

Comment: Just wanted to confirm: if the operation already executed after the delay, next call to `schedule()` should schedule a new operation, correct?

Comment: Shouldn’t the `deferred = null` write also be synchronized?

Comment: @broot yes, that's how the working JS example works

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it that should be robust even when there are exceptions in `schedulable` and another edge case I'll describe below.
You don't have to return anything from `schedule`, I just did it like this to experiment.

```kotlin
import kotlinx.coroutines.*
import kotlinx.coroutines.future.asCompletableFuture
import kotlin.concurrent.thread

object SchedulableAttempt {
    private const val DELAY_MS = 500L
    private val coroutineScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO)
    private var coroutine: Job? = null

    private fun schedulable() {
        println("schedulable function is running")
    }

    @Synchronized
    fun schedule() = coroutine.let {
        when (it?.isCompleted) {
            null -> launch()
            false -> it
            true -> launch()
        }
    }

    private fun launch(): Job {
        return coroutineScope.launch {
            println("delaying")
            delay(DELAY_MS)
            reset()
            schedulable()
        }.also {
            coroutine = it
        }
    }

    @Synchronized
    private fun reset() {
        println("resetting")
        coroutine = null
    }
}

fun main() {
    thread {
        SchedulableAttempt.schedule()
        Thread.sleep(100L)
        SchedulableAttempt.schedule()
        SchedulableAttempt.schedule()
        Thread.sleep(200L)
        SchedulableAttempt.schedule()
    }

    // just to show what happens if there are cancellations/exceptions
    runBlocking {
        SchedulableAttempt.schedule().cancelAndJoin()
    }

    // just to keep the app running
    SchedulableAttempt.schedule().asCompletableFuture().get()
}
```

It's possible that, if you run this, you'll see output like this:

```
delaying
resetting
schedulable function is running
```

Namely, `delaying` appears just once.
This means the coroutine was cancelled by `cancelAndJoin` *before it even had a chance to start*.
In these cases, `reset` will not be called by the coroutine,
which is why `schedule` also handles the case where `coroutine?.isCompleted == true`.
I had initially used a try-finally inside the `launch`ed logic,
but that doesn't help,
the finally is not even "queued" if the coroutine never starts.

BTW, you need [`kotlinx-coroutines-jdk8`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jetbrains.kotlinx/kotlinx-coroutines-jdk8) if you want the `future` extensions in the JVM and you're using a version of `kotlinx-coroutines-core` older than 1.7.0.